# chrome automatically deletes port numbers in url，Why it would be like this and how to aviod it?

Tags: url, browser

When I type a url on chrome,such as

https://xxxxx.xxx.com:8443/login,

this is my company'login web which is use to connect my Company's VPN,After typing the url will become

https://xxxxx.xxx.com/login

automatically.Why would be like this and how to aviod it?I can't go to the right website.

Fot safty I did't left the real url.

I try to change a browser such as firefox,some times It works,but some times It only can be use at a time,then the question happen again.